# UISplitViewControllers DetailViewController has wrong contentInste.bottom when MasterViewController is in search mode

Tags: ios, uitableview, layout, keyboard, uisearchbar

I ran into this strange issue while developing a universal iOS app. My app looks rather simple. At the root, I have a `UITableViewController`. The first tab contains a `UISplitViewController`. The master of the `UISplitViewController` is a `UINavigationController` with a `UITableViewController` and the detail is a `UINavigationController` with a `UITableViewController` as well.

Additionally, the master table view has a search bar in its `tableHeaderView` which I use to filter the entries. This all works as expected but I see one issue appearing on devices where the `UISplitViewController` is showing master and detail at the same time (e. g. iPad or big screen iPhone:

**PROBLEM:** When the keyboard is active in the search bar of the master, the `tableView` of the detail has a wrong `contentInset.bottom`.

**CAUSE:** I use `tableView.contentInset.top` and `tableView.contentInset.bottom` together with `tableView.bounds.height` to calculate the map cell height in `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` depending on how many other cells I display.

I debugged it and normally, the `.top` inset is 64 and the `.bottom` is 49 which are the expected values for the statusbar + navigationbar and the tabbar. However, when the keyboard is active in the searchbar, the `.bottom` inset becomes 104 which is 49 of the tabbar *PLUS* the 55 of the keyboard toolbar. As you can see, the keyboard toolbar overlays the tabbar and does not just shift it up and I think the tableview is calculating its `.bottom` inset wrongly.

**QUESTION:** What must I do so that the `tableView.contentInset.bottom` is 0 when there is no tabbar, 49 if there is a tabbar and 55 if there is a toolbar overlaying the tabbar?

[image: See how the map is shifted up when the keyboard toolbar is enabled?]

See how the map is shifted up when the keyboard toolbar is enabled? This is because in `tableView(_:heightForRowAt:)` the `tableView.contentInset.bottom` is 104 instead of 55.

[image: Does not happen when the keyboard is not active]

If the keyboard is not active / the searchbar is not focused, the `tableView.contentInset.bottom` is returning the correct height of 49.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**

It turned out that there was just a bug in IQKeyboardManager. After a recent update of the library, everything went back to normal and worked as expected even without handling any keyboard notifications by myself which is pretty nice.

**ORIGINAL ANSWER**

I managed to work around this issue by registering for UIKeyboard notifications and manually changing the tableViews `scrollViewInsets` and `contentInsets` like this:

```
func viewDidLoad(){
    ...
    let center = NotificationCenter.default
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillShow(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillShow, object: nil)
    center.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(keyboardWillHide(_:)), name: .UIKeyboardWillHide, object: nil)
}

func keyboardWillShow(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
    guard let endFrame = (userInfo[UIKeyboardFrameEndUserInfoKey] as? NSValue)?.cgRectValue else { return }
    let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
    let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
    let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
    let animationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

    self.keyboardHeight = endFrame.size.height
    self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = endFrame.size.height
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = endFrame.size.height

    let animations: () -> Void = {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                   delay: TimeInterval(0),
                   options: animationCurve,
                   animations: animations,
                   completion: nil)
}

func keyboardWillHide(_ notification: Notification) {
    guard let userInfo = notification.userInfo else { return }
    let duration:TimeInterval = (userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationDurationUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber)?.doubleValue ?? 0
    let animationCurveRawNSN = userInfo[UIKeyboardAnimationCurveUserInfoKey] as? NSNumber
    let animationCurveRaw = animationCurveRawNSN?.uintValue ?? UIViewAnimationOptions.curveEaseInOut.rawValue
    let animationCurve:UIViewAnimationOptions = UIViewAnimationOptions(rawValue: animationCurveRaw)

    self.keyboardHeight = 0.0
    self.tableView.contentInset.bottom = 49.0
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets.bottom = 49.0

    let animations: () -> Void = {
        self.tableView.beginUpdates()
        self.tableView.endUpdates()
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    }

    UIView.animate(withDuration: duration,
                   delay: TimeInterval(0),
                   options: animationCurve,
                   animations: animations,
                   completion: nil)

}
```